# For my collectionview in a tableview, how can I retrieve data from Firebase for the same indexpath?

Tags: swift, firebase, uicollectionview

[Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcvBn.png)
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvqRK.png)

I have a tableview in which I have a collectionview. 
My tableView works fine to retrieve data but I want to retrieve some data from the same row to be displayed on my collectionView.

i have an extension for Collectionview as below but I couldnt manage to reach the same indexpath.row as the tableview.

```
func retrieveSurveys() {

    let surveysDB = Database.database().reference().child("surveys")
    surveysDB.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>

        let question = snapshotValue["question"]!
        let type = snapshotValue["type"]!
        let count = snapshotValue["count"]!
        let filled = snapshotValue["filled"]!
        let sender = snapshotValue["sender"]!
        let option1 = snapshotValue["option1"]!
        let option2 = snapshotValue["option2"]!

        let surveyRetrieved = SurveyClass()
        surveyRetrieved.question = question
        surveyRetrieved.type = type
        surveyRetrieved.count = count
        surveyRetrieved.filled = filled
        surveyRetrieved.sender = sender
        surveyRetrieved.option1 = option1
        surveyRetrieved.option2 = option2

        self.surveyArray.append(surveyRetrieved)

        self.configureTableView()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

extension HomeTableViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: collectionViewCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: implement collectionViews `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
             didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` delegate method.

Comment: Dear Channu. Thank you so much for your reply. Sorry but I am a beginner and I dont know what to do afterwards after implementing the above function.

Comment: let me know what exact data you want on click of collectionView data

Comment: Hi Channu. Thank you for your valuable time. I added 2 pictures on top to explain better as I am not very competent to give details. Basically i want my horizontal collection view cells to display options of a question. The number of options varies. And my tableview to display question, type of question etc. That I could do but I cannot display my options properly.

Comment: Now understood ur requirement. Basically, you want to create app kind of quiz where q's and answers will be there.

Comment: Yes Channu. But the number of answers are different for each question.